DNS server with private authentication
I want to run a DNS server on a VPS, but I don't want to expose it to the world for safety reasons (DDoS attacks), so I want it to only be usable by myself from two devices - Windows laptop and Android phone. I want to do this without using a VPN on any of my devices, I simply just want to add the DNS ip address to my devices and have them connect to my DNS server, and block any other devices
I can't figure out how to do this. My initial thought is:

Set up a firewall to block all network traffic
Whitelist the IP of both of my devices

The issue here obviously is that my IP addresses are dynamic. Is there work around this? A few solutions that come to mind (but not sure if they're possible):

Find a way to authenticate my firewall settings via certificates installed on both of my devices.
Periodically query and transmit the public ip of my devices to my server via something like ssh.
Use DoH to authenticate clients by sending a secret, though I'm not sure how I can do this with Android, since I don't have access to the DNS client
Set up DDNS for my clients (not sure if this is possible in Android)

Curious whether these solutions are possible, and if so, which tools would you use? I didn't do very well in my networking class, would appreciate simple and thorough ELI5 explanations to why/why not :)

Just use a VPN. Implementing anything else would require a LOT of networking know-how.

Why do you not want to use a VPN?

without using a VPN — this is a strong requirement, it needs a heavy reasoning (because it's by far most correct solution for your problem), else it's off topic here on ServerFault as "unreasonable business practice".

I assume you consider this more of an experiment or a proof of concept, because from a practical standpoint, as mentioned in the above comment, what you're trying to do is an overkill - way too complicated and involving tons of tools, each of which could fail or be misconfigured. Using a VPN is much, much simpler and offers additional benefits besides the self-hosted DNS.
That said, I'll try to give my thoughts on your scenario:
Every serious DNS server has a white-/blacklisting functionality for single IPs as well as subnets. Whether you configure this at the nameserver itself, or in a firewall that sits in front of it, doesn't make much of a difference. The practical differences are:

a firewall is much more hardened and efficient at filtering traffic, since that's its only job. Any other server software has this as a side feature
in case you're using BIND as a nameserver - apparently there is no way to tell BIND to silently drop (= don't respond to) requests coming from blacklisted IPs. Instead it replies with a REFUSED error code, which denies usage of the DNS service itself, but exposes the existence of such as server. Other DNS software may have such a feature, I don't know.
depending on the firewall you're using, it may be able to learn or recognize patterns of traffic and dynamically block IPs based on that

Regarding the dynamic IP issue - it's worth giving a thought about "how dynamic" your IPs actually are. Chances are, you're using a handful of fixed providers - one at home, another at work and a third one on your mobile devices. Mobile network operators run millions of devices, but they run on a private IP range (usually 10./8) and are NATed behind a bunch of public IP subnets. Consumer ISPs also usually have a fixed IP subnet for a given city/neighborhood. You can find which public IPs your providers use and whitelist only those. Yes, you'll be whitelisting all other devices from clients of the same operator, but this is still a fraction of the entire internet. It could be a risk you may be willing to take. Either way, even if you whitelist the single IP your particular device is currently using, since this is a NAT IP, all other clients behind that NAT will be able to access your DNS as well.
Regarding authentication, DNS by its very nature and design is a public service. That's why there is no client authentication built into the protocol. Even the server-side authentication (of the response) via DNSSEC is not widely used, even though available for like 20 years now.
DNS over HTTP can be wrapped behind any HTTP authentication (basic auth, client cert, etc.), however I'm not aware of any DNS client that actually supports authenticated DoH. This would need to be configured at the OS-level in Windows, iOS, Android.
So yes, use a VPN :-)

The work around for dynamic ip traffic restriction is to use a VPN.

I want to do this without using a VPN on any of my devices

Well then, your only option is to install the DNS service on each of your devices instead.
